# Can I reassign an MEF Shared export?

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism, mef

I have a class that is `DataContract` serialized, and also marked as a shared MEF `[Export]`.

example:

```
[DataContract(Name="MyClass")]
[Export(typeof(MyClass))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Field1{get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string Field2{get;set;}

    public static MyClass Deserialize(XElement serialized)
    {
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        MyClass anotherMyClass = (MyClass)ser.ReadObject(serialized.CreateReader());

        return anotherMyClass;
    }
}
```

I have this marked as a shared export because I only want one instance at a time, but if I reassign an MEF `[Import]`ed instance of this class (by calling the `Deserialize` in an assignment) will it still be a singleton? Also, will the other Imported instances reflect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PartCreationPolicy` only applies to parts created by MEF. Your `Deserialize` method doesn't use MEF, so it will create a new instance. The instance created and managed by MEF will not be updated to match the new instance.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand the enforcement of the singleton is only when an instance is using MEF. I want to make sure I gave enough details about the reassignment portion. Say I have two view models, `ViewModel1` and `ViewModel2`, that both Import `MyClass`. If `ViewModel1` reassigns its imported instance of `MyClass` then `ViewModel2` is still using the instance it imported before the reassignment? I believe that's what you're saying, just wanting to make sure. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ethan: Yes, that's right; if `ViewModel1` replaces its imported instance of `MyClass` with a new instance, that change won't be visible to `ViewModel2`. However, if `ViewModel1` changes a property on the imported instance, that change *will* be visible to `ViewModel2`, because they're both looking at the same instance.